# 301 redirection works but status showing 302, how to fix this?

Tags: redirection

I have made redirection old url to new one using the redirection but status show the following

> ---
>
> ### 302 Found
>
> Status:    302 Found
>   Code:  302
>   Date:  Thu, 27 Aug 2015 12:01:37 GMT
>   Content-Type:  text/html
>   Connection:    close
>   Set-Cookie:    exp_tracker=a%3A1%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A7%3A%22page404%22%3B%7D; path=/
>   X-Powered-By:   PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11
>   Location:  http://www.collegenews.com/
>   Server:    cloudflare-nginx
>   CF-RAY:    21c79f6fc727270e-FRA

How to make 302 into the 301.

Comment: What is the redirect mechanism? An htaccess rule? An EE function redirect? Raw PHP location change headers?

Comment: An EE redirection function.

Comment: I used like this $CI->functions->redirect('/','location', 301);